# Not accepting any new connections. Raspberry pi zero W

Tags: python, linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I am new to StackOverflow. I have been working on monitoring service(python based) on RPi Zero W and edited the /etc/rc.local file to execute the program during the startup. The program works perfectly for first 45 - 90 mins of runtime. But after that, HTTP API on the service doesn't respond and it doesn't start accepting any new SSH connections after that time period

These are my findings

**ISSUE**

RPi is not accepting any new connections (SSH, HTTP) after 45 - 90 mins of runtime

**Findings**

1. After 45 - 90 mins, I get a sound prompt on PuTTY(Windows) on existing SSH connections to RPi(No error message popup). All the existing SSH connections would work perfectly fine
2. After that sound prompt, cannot create any new SSH connections
3. I hooked up the RPi to a screen to view for any exceptions thrown by the code. But after the prompt, the screen is frozen
4. When I run "top" command in the existing SSH terminal, it shows that the python task is still running

**Things I did to fix it**

1. Turned off the power management on WiFi interface
2. Looked at the syslog and kernel logs, did not find anything regarding that

But nothing worked out for me. Do let me know if you find anything or encountered something similar. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is for specific programming questions, so this question would be better suited for the [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Also, if you're new, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section.

Comment: @stevieb Which category under “off topic” do you use in these kinds of situations?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I use "Other", then manually type in the URLs for the related site.